# Exchange Partial Derivative wrt. to a Function (Function is depedent on variable of integration)

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, derivatives, partial-derivative, leibniz-integral-rule

At the moment I am facing a challenge concerning the exchange of an integral and a partial derivative. Not sure, if it is right, but is there any assumption that the following holds or what is the correct solution:

$\frac{\partial}{\partial f(x,t)}\int_a^bf(x,t)^2 -g(x,t)dt = \int_a^b 2f(x,t)dt$

I am facing two problems that might not be problems:

a) the derivative $\partial f(x,t)$ depends on the integral variable $dt$. This case is not covered in the Leibniz rule, as far as I understand. Can I still exchange the partial derivative and the integral?

b) If I derive $g(x,t)$ wrt to $f(x,t)$ is it really 1, although they depend on the same variables?

Help and any ideas are really much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I am not sure, how $\frac{\partial}{\partial f(x,t)}$ is supposed to be interpreted. Can you give some more context? If I would have to guess, this looks like a formal way of describing some kind of first variation of an energy functional. Or similarly the calculation of an Euler-Lagrange equation.

Comment: It seems to be change of coordinate mapping of $\langle x,t\rangle\mapsto\langle f,g\rangle$, and asking if somehow $\tfrac{\partial}{\partial f} \int_a^b (f^2-g)\,\mathrm d t=\int_a^b \tfrac{\partial}{\partial f}(f^2-g)\,\mathrm d t$ .  ....

Comment: @humanStampedist This is a survival model in Statistics. So the probability of survival is dependent on the time and the x vector. I just made it easier, as my core problem is the analysis part :)

Comment: It is more about the mathematical part if I can do what @GrahamKemp is possible... and under which assumptions and what happens if I derive one function with respect to another function with the same preimage...

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i2d=true&i=Partial%5BIntegrate%5BPower%5Bf%28x%5C%28%2C%29t%29%2C2%5D+%E2%88%92g%28x%5C%28%2C%29t%29%2C%7Bt%2Cb%2Ca%7D%5D%2Cf%28x%5C%28%2C%29t%29%5D

Comment: I just need a clue, if Wolfram Alpha is right and why... Because I cannot find a mathematical rule which allows me to do it.

Comment: I think it is highly related to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative
But still have a knot in my brain...

Comment: Do you have any precise definition of what $\frac{\partial}{\partial f(x,t)}$ is supposed to mean? What is the goal of your calculation? Does it come from a paper or is it homework? If it comes from a paper or book, you might want to link it. Do you definitely know that $\int_a^b 2 f(x,t)\, dt$ is your solution?

Comment: @humanStampedist It should be the "pseudo-residual" in gradient boosting (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_boosting). So neither from a paper nor homework. Here, you optimize a loss function in functional space. No, I am not sure, if this is the correct solution. Just asking myself, if wolfram alpha is correct...

Comment: What is your loss function $L$ then? It cannot be $L(f,x)=\int_a^b(f(x,t))^2 + g(x,t)\, dt$ because then $L$ would depend on the whole function $f$. In your wikipedia article $L$ only depends on an evaluated point of $f$, i.e. $f(x)$, not the whole of $f$.

Comment: @humanStampedist Sorry, for the confusion so the actual loss function I care about is the Integrated Brier Score (https://square.github.io/pysurvival/metrics/brier_score.html , https://mlr3proba.mlr-org.com/reference/mlr_measures_surv.graf.html) with censoring weights (IPCW)  $L(f(x), y) = \int_0^{\tau} weight(t*,\delta, t) \cdot (f(x \mid t) - \mathcal{I}(t < t^*))^2 dt$ with y is t* and $\delta$.  y= 1 if t < t* and y= 0 if t $\geq$ t*

Comment: you are right. So maybe it is right to do $\frac{\partial}{\partial f(x)}$, but f is still depending on t and x..?

Comment: Maybe this framework of the pseudo-residual is not yet applicable, because it only allows $L$ which only accept real numbers. Your $L$ here accepts a whole function. You could maybe approximate the integral by a Riemannian sum and start working from there, because then you would only need evaluations of $f$ at finitely many points.

Comment: You could also write for a normal squared loss (maybe a bit sloppy notation): 
$$
r(f)=-\frac{\partial 0.5(y-f)^{2}}{\partial f}=y-f
$$

Not sure... you may be right.. normally you have just a function of f(x) and not f(t|x) ... but by integrating it over t you also have just one value for one x.

ok, and with finitely many points the derivative is no problem?

Comment: I don't know if there will be a problem with only finitely many values. This is just an idea I had to maybe circumvent the problem. I'm really not sure. This whole question sounds like a research question for a thesis. Do you have an advisor? She/He might help out.

Comment: Unfortunately, so far nobody could help me.